# SeekToCurrentBatchLogErrorHandler.handle not Being a called when exception thrown with explicit BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

Using Spring-kafka 2.2.7.
SeekToCurrentBatchLogErrorHandler handle method is not being called when an exception is thrown when creating an explicit BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener (non annotated KafkaListener).  I was able to see a BatchLoggingErrorHandler.handle error in the tomcat logs. Does this work with an explict BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener?

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> 
      kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory =
          new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        containerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.BATCH);
        containerFactory.setBatchListener(true);
        SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler errorHandler =new SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler();
        containerFactory.setBatchErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        return containerFactory;
    }
```

```
@Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> messageListenerContainer() {
        String topic = "topicname";
        String beanName = "CustomBatchListener";

        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topic);
        containerProperties.setMessageListener(new CustomBatchListener());
        containerProperties.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> listenerContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(
                consumerFactory(), containerProperties);

        listenerContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
        listenerContainer.setBeanName(beanName);

        return listenerContainer;
}
```

```
public class CustomBatchListener implements BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener<String, String> {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomBatchListener.class);
    public CustomBatchListener() {

    }
    private void handleMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Throwing exeception");
      throw new Exception("Exception is thrown");

    }
    /**
     * Receiver method from spring-kafka. Receives the polled messages from spring
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records, Acknowledgment acknowledge) {

            try {
                this.handleMessage(records);
                acknowledge.acknowledge();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(););
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Basically had to update to Spring-Kafka 2.3.4 and @KafkaListener to get this to work.

Comment: What versions did you update to? I would upvote if there was a little more info...

Comment: I updated spring and spring-kafka to Spring 5.2.2, Spring-Kafka 2.3.4.  I also started using the @KafkaAnnotation rather than implementing my own batchListener and now SeekToCurrent BatchErrorHandler is working as advertised.